# Create generic selector for Select() while using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, select, lambda

I would like to create a function to retrieve a List of a given property name's Type. But i dont know yet how to create a working lambda selector.

```
public IList<object> GetDistinctListOfProperty(string propertyName)
{
    var propInfoByName = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (propInfoByName == null) return new List<object>();

    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var lambda = //TODO
        return db.Set<T>().Select(lambda).Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to pass in the property name as a string? Could you pass in an Expression instead?

Comment: i am working with nameof(modelClass.property) as parameter, thats why string is used. @RenéVogt yes true thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this method to generate lambda

```
public static Expression<Func<T, object>> LambdaGenerator<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "current");
        var property = Expression.Property(arg, propertyName);
        var conv = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));
        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(conv, new ParameterExpression[] { arg });
        return exp;
    }
```

and then use this method to create your expression

```
var lambda = LambdaGenerator<T>("Your Property Name");
```

Comment: had to change object to string, to use it also to populate my comboboxes but it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an expression for this:

```
private IList<Tout> GetDistinctListOfProperty<Ttable, Tout>(Expression<Func<Ttable, Tout>> returnField) where Ttable : class
{
    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        return db.Set<Ttable>().Select(returnField).Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```

You need to wrap the `Func` into an `Expression` so that entity can translate it into a valid sql. This version allows you to use intellisense when you choose your parameter. You would call it like this:

```
var result = GetDistinctListOfProperty<YourTableType>(x => x.YourProperty);
```

This version will work on every table that is known to your `ApplicationDbContext`

Comment: @eddywhite then you probably should use `Set<Ttable>`. I edited my post, please try again