# Using Distinct in generic DbSet queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, distinct

I'm trying to run a Distinct query against an Entity Framework `DbSet`.  The lists are used to populate Selects in the UI for filtering datasets of `TRecord`.  The full method is listed below.  `fieldName` is one of the fields in `DbSet`.  The code below works but's inefficient.  If you try to use `Distinct()` directly on the `DbSet` it doesn't do a distinct - just returns the full dataset.  I'm assuming the problem lies in the way I'm using reflection to get the value.  Is there a solution?

```
public async static Task<List<string>> GetDistinctListAsync<TRecord>(this DbContext context, string fieldName) where TRecord : class, IDbRecord<TRecord>, new()
{
     // Get the DbSet for TRecord
     var dbset = GetDbSet<TRecord>(context, null);
     // declare list as an empty list
     var list = new List<string>();
     // Get the filter propertyinfo object
     var x = typeof(TRecord).GetProperty(fieldName);
     if (dbset != null && x != null)
     {
          // we get the full list and then run a distinct because we can't run a distinct directly on the dbSet
          var fulllist = await dbset.Select(item => x.GetValue(item).ToString()).ToListAsync();
          list = fulllist.Distinct().ToList();
     }
     return list ?? new List<string>();
}
```

I'm reworking my older code that used a SQL Distinct Query called through `DbSet.FromSQLRaw()`.

Comment: Can you include the code you're trying to translate?

Comment: It's inefficient because you fetch everything and process it in-memory.... This thread may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619338/ef-distinctby-on-an-iqueryable

Comment: Hi Alexandru, the question below answered my problem, so I'll trouble you no more.  My production code was running on DbSet.FromSQLRaw(), I was trying to get away from the raw SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caveat that I don't know what magic `GetDbSet<TRecord>` does, here's a replacement function that'll take care of it, inspired by:
[Create generic selector for Select() while using Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56789640/create-generic-selector-for-select-while-using-entity-framework)

```
public static async Task<List<string>> GetDistinctListAsync<TRecord>(this DAL.DbContext context, string fieldName) where TRecord : class
    {
        var dbset = context.Set<TRecord>();

        // Return value.
        List<string> list = null;

        if (dbset != null) // Found matching dbSet
        {
            // Convert our property into a lambda expression.
            var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TRecord), "current");
            var property = Expression.Property(arg, fieldName);
            var conv = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));
            var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<TRecord, object>>(conv, new ParameterExpression[] { arg });

            list = 
                (await dbset.Select(exp).Distinct().ToArrayAsync()) // This runs against database / SQL
                .Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList(); // Convert return values into strings locally if necessary.
        }
        return list ?? new List<string>();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,  that works great.  I couldn't see the wood for the trees!

Comment: Hi @ShaunCurtis if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Done.  You learn some thing new ever day! FYI the code is part of a generics based Data Access Layer Service for Blazor.  `GetDbSet` just gets the correct DbSet from the EF DbContext.